# ScreenCapture by WebRTC in Swift

Tags: swiftui, webrtc, screen, share, replaykit

I want to share screen to other users by WebRTC in Swift.

I have established webrtc connections.
What I need is this, I need to send RTCVideoTrack via connection.
I can get the user's videotracks from the camera with RTCVideoCapturer. However, when I screen share, I need to convert the screenshots to Videotrack and send them.

What's the best way to do this? Is ReplayKit the right method for this? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You probably want to use ScreenCaptureKit to capture screen share frames. Note that this doesn't have anything to do with SwiftUI, which is a UI framework and app lifecycle. You'll be better off changing your searching to just Swift.